# "Undeleting" partition (NTFS) - recommendations?

Tags: ntfs, partition-recovery

So I have a drive which either suffered from hardware error or, possibly, got a little shock from badly configured Windows unattended install started on the same PC (the drive in question wasn't the install drive..).

Quick exam shows that filesystem is seemingly intact, as some data recovery tools work with it (UnFormat rated it as "Excellent"). This may mean that a copy of partition table exists on disk, or a copy of MFT survived whatever happened, or..

---

Any idea how to restore partition tables/FS header, add a drive letter thus let Windows to mount the filesystem as if nothing happened?

Answer (score 0):

G4L (Ghost 4 Linux) / TestDisk has always worked for me.  You can download a bootable ISO from sourceforge.  As always if you care about data best to backup before using anything that writes.